# Why does casting 1782 to byte yield -10 in Java?

Tags: java, casting

```
int i;
byte b;

i = 1782;

b = (byte) i;

System.out.print(b);
```

Here I get `-10` but cannot understand why. Please explain my how casts in Java work.